# Why next-auth middleware redirect logged user?

Tags: next.js, prisma, next-auth

I had made auth with next-auth via Github. After signing in with Github, `useSession` from `next-auth/react` on client works correctly. And `getServerSession` from `next-auth/next` works correctly.
But middleware always redirect (for logged user and for unlogged user).

I'm using Next.js 13 with app router and  next-auth 4.

middleware is:

```js
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware'

export const config = { matcher: ["/path_with_auth1", "/path_with_auth2"] }
```

Options is:

```js
export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};
```

app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import { options } from './options'

const handler = NextAuth(options);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

I'm expecting It will redirect only unlogged user. Can you help me? How make it work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to nextAuth documentation, by default the session strategy is set to `jwt` but when an adapter is provided, it defaults to `database`

For me setting session strategy to `jwt` solved the issue.

Your options should now looks like this:

```js
export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};
```

Buy doing this, you are overriding the default strategy from database to jwt since u have provided a adapter